# pdsh in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script as follows,

```
#!/bin/bash
zone=$1
if  [ "$zone" == "A" ]; then
    pdsh -l abc -w server[01-12] 'sudo abc stop'
elif ["$zone" == "B" ]; then
    pdsh -l abc -w server[1-12].abc.def.com 'sudo abc stop'
fi
```

The server string `.abc.def.com` is throwing an error. What can i do to make it accept the string

Comment: line 13: [abc: command not found

Comment: Don't mix single bracket notation `[` with `==`, this is against POSIX and only works because `bash` is forgiving. Use `[ ... = ... ]` or `[[ ... == ... ]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space in your `elif` line:

```
elif [ "$zone" == "B" ]; then
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. I thought the server string was causing issues. Thanks